# Flutter document Firestore is not deleting [CLOSE]

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to delete document in firestore with this function,

[UPDATE] following code from the documentation

```
class DatabaseService {
  final String uid;
  final String taskId;
  final String boardId;

  DatabaseService({this.uid, this.taskId, this.boardId});
    
///delete task
      Future<void> deleteTask() async {
        return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('user')
            .doc(uid)
            .collection('tasks')
            .doc(taskId)
            .delete()
            .then((value) => print('task $taskId deleted'))
            .catchError((error) => print("Failed to delete task: $error"));
      }
}
```

[image]
I put wrong collection name, supposedly tasks. I already update with the right name.

trigger button:

```
IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.delete_outline,
                color: kColorRed,
              ),
              onPressed: () async {
                print('task delete pressed');
                print(widget.userId);
                print(widget.taskId);
                await DatabaseService(uid: widget.userId, taskId: widget.taskId)
                    .deleteTask();
                Navigator.pop(context);
              }),
```

output:

```
flutter: task delete pressed
flutter: VWtHv8LPE3brezl9a5zmHlwYM5h2
flutter: [#9bb27]
flutter: VWtHv8LPE3brezl9a5zmHlwYM5h2 task [#9bb27] deleted
```

inside the document:

[image]

it back with the print result. But, when I checked on Firestore, the document still there.
Am I doing it right?

Comment: can you please check `taskId` contains the correct document reference id?  

btw. you should not used both `await `  and `...then` at the same time.

Comment: Can you share the output of print statement

Comment: @beerstorm can you enlighten me why I cannot use await and then at the same time? do you have better suggestion to get the output?. I'm pretty sure taskId is correct, because output of print has the same task_id with the document I want to delete.

Comment: @Siddharthjha the output task [#8e58c] deleted

Comment: using `await is the preferred way and you already can get the result as the output of this ` await Firestore...` ,  appending another `.then` is unnecessary and not usable other than extra logging purposes.

Comment: Have you checked if the path of the task is same in your console and code?

Comment: @beerstorm I am using it to logging purposes

Comment: @Siddharthjha multiple times, that is the first thing I did. I am wondering whether the comment is outdated or any other possibilities. It was running well

Comment: @Alamsyah Can you try and do a `get()` on the subcollection to check if it returnings anything

Comment: @PeterHaddad I am on process upgrading the plugin version and cocoapods. I just check there are a lot of update in the plugin, I'm afraid that update make the function is not working. I cannot share the result right now, but I'm sure it return something, because my Widget is working. I'm using StreamBuilder as well.

Comment: @Alamsyah I'd reinforce to check the value of the "value" variable, maybe you can try to print it in order to check what object are you interacting with.

Comment: There's not enough information here.  We can't see what you're passing for `uid` and `taskId`, so we don't know if you're deleting the correct document.  A delete will not fail if the document doesn't already exist.  Please edit the question to show the values you're using here, and a screenshot that shows that the values match the document in the console.

Comment: @DougStevenson really appreciate your word, I miss one alphabet there, supposedly 'tasks' not 'task'. I did dumb mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem .

I have solve this by check userid is passing or not .I mean getting the value for userid

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).